# How to get data from dictionary interface in Typescript?

Tags: dictionary, typescript

I've declare my interface like this

```
export interface IBookBorrower {
  _id?: string
  name?: string
  age?: number
  [books: string]: any
}
```

And when I getting data I do like this

```
 for (var bookId in this.borrower) 
   console.log(bookId, this.borrower[bookId]))
```

I receive all data includes _id, name and age that I don't want, 
How can I get data only in "books" ?

Comment: `for (var book in this.borrower.books)` should bring back just the books.

Comment: @MetroSmurf seems like I can not do like this no 'books' does not exist, I have try it and no data

Answer (score 3):

Typescript is just javascript with types so what you are asking for (iterating on just part of the same object interface) just cannot work.

You need to make books its own property in the borrower object, it's probably cleaner anyway.

```
export interface IBookBorrower {
  _id?: string
  name?: string
  age?: number
  books: { [id: string]: any }
}

 for (var bookId in this.borrower.books) 
   console.log(bookId, this.borrower[bookId]))
```

Comment: I think so, but I want to do that as my way to keep data in mongodb easily. Seems like I have to changes it :p

Comment: Come on, mongodb handles nested objects just fine :p